# Preload Picasso Image with StaggeredGridLayout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, staggeredgridlayout

I have a StaggeredGridLayoutManager that loads 20 cards which contain images (loaded from cache, network, or storage with Picasso) in a 2 column wide grid.

**Issue:**

Currently, as you scroll down the list the images are loaded as the cards slide into view like this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xMNmMjqEbI

**Desired solution:**

What I would like to happen is for the images to load offscreen, so there is a seamless UX like this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4c7ZID7yjII

These videos are from a blog post which solves this problem using *LinearLayoutManager*, not *StaggeredGridLayoutManager*. I cannot seem to figure out the equivalent solution for this issue. I'm fairly new to android development and have tried to read through the documentation but I canot seem to find anything leading to a solution.

**Code:**

```
    // Setup RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_posts);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // Setup StaggeredGridLayoutManager
    mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // Set Adapter
    mPostsAdapter = new PostAdapter(rootView.getContext(), posts);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mPostsAdapter);

    // Start RestClient & get posts
    restClient = new RestClient(getString(R.string.api_location));
    getPosts();
```

Answer (score 3):

Preload the images to show in a cache, so instead of loading them while you scroll the list, they're already on memory.

```
 Picasso.with(this).load("url").fetch();
```

Also, remove the Picasso fadeIn animation.

```
Picasso.with(this).load("url").noFade().into(imageView);
```

Comment: All the images are already loading from cache and when i set noFade(), the images just pop in as they appear on the screen. I need to somehow set the size of the layout to be larger than the physical screen so they pop into place before the user sees the card.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out a partial solution to my own problem. Going to post it for anyone new like myself that is trying to figure this out.

The RecyclerView method **setItemViewCacheSize(int size)** will keep the disired amount of items in cache so you dont have flickering type loading of views.

I have not found a lookahead solution though to load a specific amount of views ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

For me it's working

```
Picasso.get()
 .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
 .placeholder(R.drawable.logoblack_loading)
 .config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
 .into(holder.imageView);
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/id_imgItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/id_imgItem"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```